# How to execute an Array job on SGE -

Tags: arrays, bash, sungridengine

I have 50 different fasta files that I would like to analyze using a program (glsearch36).
The files are numbered 3163proph00.fa - 3163proph49.fa.

I would like to submit these 50 almost identical jobs using to a cluster using SGE queuing system as an array job.

One problem is that SGE requires the SGE_TASK_ID to be from 1-50, so I first had to create the variable i and subtract 1 to get 0. I then created j as the numbers have a leading zero.

I am not too proficient with bash, so I am sure that I have made some syntax error in going from SGE_TASK_ID to i to j.

When I submit this file I get the following error "Illegal variable name.".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -t 1-50
#$ -e glsearch.err
#$ -o glsearch.out
#$ -N glsearch

#  really the files are 00-49
i=$(($SGE_TASK_ID - 1))
j= printf "%02d" "$i"
echo $j
/g/bor/x86_64/bin/glsearch36 -T 1 /g/bor/Viruses/3163_proph_split50/3163proph$j.fa /g/bor/Viruses/prophage_region.fna > glsearch_3163proph$j.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

- **`$`** in the **`((...))`** is not needed
- no **`space`** before and after **`=`**
- put **`printf`** into **`$(...)`**

  ```
  i=$((SGE_TASK_ID - 1))
  j=$(printf "%02d" "$i")
  ```

Comment: Thanks kev - I made your modifications but am still getting the same illegal variable name error.

Comment: did you `export SGE_TASK_ID` before running the script. Please put `echo $SGE_TASK_ID` in the script to debug.

Comment: SGE_TASK_ID is being assigned properly.  However, i and j aren't being assigned. I echoed them and they are blank.
sge task id 44

Comment: Can you run the `glsearch36` command in the shell successfully?

Comment: yes I can run glsearch.  to debug I have commented out the glsearch and am just trying to get it to echo $i and $j and I am still getting the illegal variable name error.

Comment: This is very Weird. Try to remove all comments starts with `#$`.

Comment: If it still not work. Delete everything. Just put `echo hello world` in it.

Comment: Yes strange. the i and j assignments work in isolate when just typed into the shell.  However, within the submission script they don't work.

Comment: Got it!!  I just added "#$ -S /bin/sh" to the shell script and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your job is running in a posix_compliant queue with /bin/csh as the default shell.  Because the queue is posix_compliant your #!  line is ignored and the default shell is used.  You can override the default shell with a -S directive to grid engine.

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
```